# Existence of matrix with $d_{ii} \in \{1,-1\}$ in QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n,n}$ with $QR$-decompositions $A=Q_1R_1=Q_2R_2$.

> Let be A invertible. I want to show $D \in \mathbb R^{n,n} $ exists such that, $Q_1=Q_2D$ and $R_1=DR_2$ with  with $d_{ii} \in \{-1,1\}, i=1,\dots,n$ .

We can conclude $R_2R_1^{-1}=Q_2^{-1}Q_1$. Furhtermore $R:=R_2R_1^{-1}$ is an upper triangle matrix and $Q:=Q_2^{-1}Q_1$ is orthogonal. Consider the eigenvalues $\lambda$ from $Q$. Then $\lambda \in \{-1,1\}$. Hence $r_{ii}\in\{1,-1\} \,\forall i=1,\dots n$.

How can we proceed to conclude $Q=R=D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $R=Q $ is both upper triangular and orthogonal. So $Q^T=Q^{-1} $ is both lower triangular and upper triangular.

Comment: ok becuase of $Q$ is orthogonal $Q^T=Q^{-1}$ holds and since Q is upper triangular Q^T is lower triangular. Okay, thank you !

Comment: The second part of this exercise asked for a counter example for this statement for a non-invertible matrix $A$. But can't you always choose $D = I_n$ or $D = -I_n$, where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$-identity matrix?

Comment: If you choose $D$ invertible, then $A$ would be invertible. And if $D=I$, then $A$ is orthogonal.